# Split_Part equivalent for Kdb+

Tags: sql, kdb, vertica

working through using Kdb, not as familiar with our schema and tables..so still learning here.

But there is a column a called Action with string values: `Behavior|5*100-6*200|StrategyXYZ`

In sql, I can split this string like

`split_part(Action, "|", 3,) Behavior`  -> `StrategyXYZ`

What is the equivalent for kdb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `vs` to split the string by delimiter and take the element at desired index. You can wrap this into a single function like so:

```
f: {(y vs x) [z]}
f["yourstring";"|";2]  /for single string
select f[;"|";2] each yourstringcolumn from yourtable /for a column in table
```

Comment: Cheers. Please mark the answer as Accepted if it solved your problem

Comment: Curious, is it possible to run this without defining a function?  I tried running {(y vs x) [z]}  where z = yourstringcolumn however no luck

Comment: If you want to run without a function then can do `select ("|" vs' yourstringcolumn)[;2] from t`. The ' is an iterator that's taking the place of the `each` in the original answer